# If i set simple view of Recycler View child item height to match_parent it becomes invisible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a simple view on the left of my `RecyclerView` item layout which looks like this

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/status_view"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/pending_color_my_schedule" />
```

I need it to full height of his parent (RelativeLayout) like this

[image]

Code of parent layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/my_schedule_item_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/my_schedule_item_margins"
      android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/my_schedule_item_margins"
      android:background="@drawable/shadow_212838"/>

But when I set my `View` to `match_parent's` height it becomes invisible and I can't find a clue why.

If I set it to 150dp or 200dp it works, but I need it to be flexible as the height of parent.

Entire XML file (UPD)

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/my_schedule_item_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/my_schedule_item_margins"
  android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/my_schedule_item_margins"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"
  android:background="@drawable/shadow_212838">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/time_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_start"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins"
    android:textColor="@color/black_standart"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:text="Tomorrow: 11:45 - 15:00" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/status_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Pending" />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/status_color_image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/my_schedule_item_status_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/my_schedule_item_status_size"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_schedule_status_icon_top_padding"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/status_text"
    android:background="@drawable/pending_circle" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/location_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/time_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/time_text"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_grey"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    tools:text="Factory and Co Aeroville" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/function_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_small"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/time_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/location_text"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/my_schedule_text_margins_start"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    tools:text="Function: Manager" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/decline_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/my_schedule_item_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/my_schedule_item_button_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/my_schedule_item_buttons_bottom_padding"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/function_text"
    android:layout_below="@id/function_text"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_transparent_btn_bg"
    android:text="@string/decline"
    android:textColor="@color/clear_blue" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/confirm_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/my_schedule_item_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/my_schedule_item_button_height"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/my_schedule_item_buttons_bottom_padding"
    android:layout_below="@id/function_text"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/decline_button"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_solid_button_bg"
    android:text="@string/confirm"
    android:textColor="@color/white_standart" />
  <View
    android:id="@+id/status_view"
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/pending_color_my_schedule" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the entire layout, which is set to match_parent. And the view is now very big and occupies the whole screen.

I can't submit it without adding the details so I will add lorem ipsum, sorry

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the parent height to `match_parent`?

Comment: I think what you are trying to archive different than what you are coding in your case, the recylerview item layout has an view like that

Comment: @EasyJoin.net, it worked, view is visible but now it is very big (whole screen) so my parent should be wrap_content

Comment: Wait I'll update the answer

Comment: @ОлегМісько My point was that if you have a parent realtive layout that in height `wrap_content` and all the child 'wrap_content' you'll see nothing because is collapsed. Now, since your RelativeLayout is inside an other layout you have to add also this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

What about change the relative's `layout_height` to `match_parent`? If it can't fix your problem, can you please place the entire xml here?

Comment: I've posted entire XML file. Your solutions make the view visible but the view occupies the whole screen.

Comment: Sure. Your layout must fill the whole RecyclerView content, it's right. Then you can control the RecyclerView's size on the RecyclerView tag

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to archive different than what you are coding, in your case the `RecyclerView` item layout should be like that

Make few changes in your code

1.Create your recycler_items.xml as follows

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fafafa">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/status_view"
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/pending_color_my_schedule" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- Your code here
            Example is given below
            -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello World!" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

2.Change your main_layout.xml as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_schedule_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvHome"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Correctly the `recyclerview_item.xml` `height` has set to `100dp`, This is just for demo purpose. **If you want to make the view as `wrap_content` that is adjustable height change all of the height attribute to `wrap_content` (including parent and child) in `recyclerview_item.xml`**

> Add the following dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0' //Check your version
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
```

Comment: Tried to wrap it in LinearLayout as you suggested - doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: @ОлегМісько I didn&#39;t wrap it in a LinearLayout. When you are creating a recycler view you need to pass a layout for that right. So add this recyclerview_item.xml as that layout it will work properly

Comment: @ОлегМісько If you need to add something in each of your recycler view item add that on the place given otherwise keep as I given